# Website javascript works locally, but not on AWS

Tags: javascript, html, amazon-web-services

I'm hosting a static website on AWS (stored in S3, with [CloudFront + Lambda@Edge](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/adding-http-security-headers-using-lambdaedge-and-amazon-cloudfront/)). I've added some basic javascript to respond to button clicks (since I will be sending the form data to AWS API Gateway using AJAX, etc), but **the javascript only seems to work locally, not online**.

To be specific, if you go to [my website](https://www.wheat-chaff.com) and click on the button, nothing happens, regardless of what you enter in the text field. But if you "View page source" and save it locally, it will respond as expected (alerts pop-up and text field changes color depending on whether or not id is valid).

I've used jslint and regex101 to check and clean my code. I've removed all CSS and unrelated content. I've also reproduced the problem on several devices and browsers (always works fine locally). I'm pretty new to AWS and Javascript, so maybe it's something basic, but I've hit a roadblock after several days. Any help would be much appreciated!

I'm reproducing the html below (for posterity):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Why U No Work???</title>

    <script>
        function submitToAwsApiGateway(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            // Validate id.
            // Length is 4-20 characters. Can have letters, numbers, spaces, and
            // some punctuation (!, @, #, &, *, (, ), -, _, +, =, [, ], |, :, .)
            // but not all ($, %, ^, {, }, ;, ", ', <, >, ?).
            const idRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#&*()_+=|:.\u0020\-\[\]]{4,20}$/;
            var idValue = document.getElementById("id").value;
            if (!idRegex.test(idValue)) {
                document.getElementById("id").style.borderColor = "red";
                window.alert("Invalid id!");
                return;
            }
            document.getElementById("id").style.borderColor = "green";
            window.alert("Regex let this pass through.");
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Blah Blah</h1>
    <form id="getRecommendations" method="post">
        <input type="text" id="id" placeholder="Enter your id" maxlength="20" autofocus>
        <button type="button" onClick="submitToAwsApiGateway(event)">Do Something!</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**
Thanks to commenters for pointing me to Developer Tools > Console in browser. I'm getting the following output:

```
Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-jTQewrwZXhw320PnyfMo9c2+HHfh5l+pWVDLQMo/7rE='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

So I think this must relate to my Lambda@Edge security measures. Namely [Content Security Policy](https://infosec.mozilla.org/guidelines/web_security#content-security-policy). I'll see if I can debug...

Comment: @smac2020 Thanks for the suggestion, but my problem is unrelated to AJAX..?

Comment: If you right click and inspect, you will see the error console messages. Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash or a nonce is required to enable inline execution. Also, for proper HTML, you should have your button type `submit` and have an onSubmit on your form. It'll avoid to execute default input post when hitting Enter in your inputs

Comment: What do the browser developer tools say?  Hint: CORS can be a pain.

Comment: This JavaScript looks' very straightforward. Are you seeing Console errors in your broswer- if so, what are they?

Comment: @stdunbar, smac2020 Thanks both for pointing me to browser developer tools > console (I did not know that errors appeared there). I've updated my post accordingly, and now have something to debug - thanks!

Comment: @JonathanHamel Thanks for the advice. I did not fully understand your last sentence; can you explain "It'll avoid to execute default input post when hitting Enter in your inputs"? Also, the AWS example code seems to suggest type button rather than submit (e.g. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/create-dynamic-contact-forms-for-s3-static-websites-using-aws-lambda-amazon-api-gateway-and-amazon-ses/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, a few key lessons I learned here:

1. Best way to debug (non-responsive) JavaScript is browser's More tools > Developer Tools > Console tab. Without this, I was flying blind.
2. **The problem was not with the JavaScript, but rather with the security headers I was adding.** I had followed [this AWS article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/adding-http-security-headers-using-lambdaedge-and-amazon-cloudfront/) without a deep understanding of the directives, and they blocked my JavaScript.
3. **Inline JavaScript is bad!** Make sure you put all your scripts into a separate file. Maybe this is obvious to you, but I had to [read this article to understand why](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/csp). Plus I have seen many Stack Overflow questions with inline JavaScript, so I question if this is really well known...
4. Use the [Mozilla Observatory](https://observatory.mozilla.org/) and [Google's CSP Evaluator](https://csp-evaluator.withgoogle.com/) to check and improve your website's security.

In the end, I used the following Content-Security-Policy headers:

```
default-src 'none';
img-src 'self';
script-src 'self';
style-src 'self';
require-trusted-types-for 'script';
base-uri 'none';
form-action 'self';
frame-ancestors 'none'
```

But of course, you should customize this according to your website's needs. Seriously, [just spend the 30 minutes to thoroughly understand this article](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/csp), and save yourself future headaches.

**UPDATE:**

I forgot to include permissions for Google reCAPTCHA, so I further updated CSP's script-src as follows:

```
default-src 'none';
script-src 'self' https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js;
img-src 'self'; [...etc...]
```

**UPDATE 2:**

As one of the comments below notes, the `require-trusted-types-for` directive should really be removed.

I also had to enable recaptcha and AWS API Gateway, so my final solution was quite a bit more complex than what I wrote above. Here it is in case it helps others:

```
default-src 'none';
connect-src AMAZON_API_GATEWAY;
img-src 'self';
font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com;
frame-src https://www.google.com/recaptcha/ https://recaptcha.google.com/recaptcha/;
script-src 'self' https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js https://www.google.com/recaptcha/ https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/;
style-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com;
base-uri 'none';
form-action 'self';
frame-ancestors 'none'
```

Comment: To save yourself real headaches - remove `require-trusted-types-for` directive ASAP. If [misused](http://csplite.com/csp/test369/), this directive [it blocks](http://csplite.com/csp/test311/#test) a lot of javascript's constructs: `element.innerHTML =...`, `document.write()`, `setAttribute('onClick', ...)`, `createElement('script')`, etc. Check your web page in latest Chrome browser.